# np.argmax does not return the correct index

Tags: python, numpy

I used `np.argmax` to search for the index of the highest value of this array:

[image]

And it returned 720. It was supposed to be 721. I tried to google the problem but haven't found the solution yet.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf, pacf

dir='C:\\Users\\DELL\\Google Drive\\JVN couse materials\\Projects\\Practice projects\\Time series project\\energydata_complete.csv'
rawdata=pd.read_csv(dir, index_col='date')
timeseries=pd.DataFrame(rawdata['Appliances'])
timeseries.index=pd.to_datetime(timeseries.index)
timeseries['Log scale']=np.log10(timeseries['Appliances'])
lag_pacf = pacf(timeseries.loc['2016-01-12':'2016-01-21','Log scale'], nlags=1439, method='ols')
highest_pacf_lag=np.argmax(lag_pacf[1:]) ###this is where the problem happens
```

Comment: There is no way np.argmax can give you wrong answer.. you have to specify the axis ... You forgot to specify the axis

Comment: Python is zero-indexed. If the screenshot is from Excel, which is one-indexed, then index 720 in Python corresponds to index 721 in Excel.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I forgot that I omitted the first entry of the array due to the fact that it's the 0-lag in the time series. That was why the np.argmax return the position 720.

Comment: The picture was cropped from Spyder :)

Answer (score 1):

`csv` file indexes values from 1 and Python (and numpy and pandas too)is zero indexed. Hence cell no 721 is shown as 720 in python